# How to use a DLL C++ in Node using SWIG?

Tags: c++, node.js, dll, swig, node-webkit

I tried to have asses to this function from a dll :

// file Mathematiques.cpp

```
int WINAPI **multipli**(int a , int b)
{
return a*b;
}
```

For information :
// file WinDef.h

```
#define WINAPI      __stdcall
```

To do that I write some C++ code which load my DLL :

// File NodeJS.cpp

```
HMODULE hDLL=LoadLibrary("D:\\1_testfiles\\Xpcom\\FonctionMath\\Debug\\FonctionMath.dll");

int Test(int a, int b){

if(!hDLL)
{
printf("Erreur de LoadLibrary");
return 1;
}

DLL_Function_multipli pfn_multipli;

pfn_multipli =(DLL_Function_multipli)GetProcAddress(hDLL,"multipli");

if (!pfn_multipli)
{
FreeLibrary(hDLL);
return 1;
}

return pfn_multipli(a,b);

}
```

And before that I declared my function in the file interface :

```
extern int Test(int a, int b);
```

Finally I build my component and I try to run this script form Node :

```
var NWMatrix = require("./build/Release/NWMatrix");

var v=NWMatrix.Test(1,9);

console.log("Multiplication Result = "+v);
```

It doesn't work, but when I tried the same script from Node-Webkit It works fine.

I thought it was a matter of version of different Node.

But I use Node 0.10.33 in my computer and Node-webkit 0.8.6 which use Node 0.10...

Why this script doesn't work ?

Any help would be very greadful !!

EDIT :

I think now It's not a matter of DLL but my code cpp is wrong...

I will explain my self :

I run this script with node :

```
var NWMatrix = require("./build/Release/NWMatrix");

console.log("\n");
row=25;
column=25;
NbrBoucle=4;

for(var k=0;k<NbrBoucle;k++){

console.time('Matrice'+row+"*"+column);
console.log("Row number=" + row);
console.log("column number=" + column);
console.log(k);

NWMatrix.MatrixCreate(row,column);
NWMatrix.Transpose();
NWMatrix.MultiplierParUnScalaire(42.5);

console.timeEnd('Matrice'+row+"*"+column);


row=row*10;
column=column*10;
NWMatrix.DestroyMatrice();
h=NWMatrix.Test(8,9+k);
console.log("Mutliplication Result ="+h);
console.log("\n");
};

var v;
v=NWMatrix.Test(5,9);

console.log("Multiplication Result = "+v);
```

In this code I make reference of this code :

```
#include "boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp"
#include "boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp"
#include "mathematiques.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> v;


int MatrixCreate(int row, int column) {
    using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
    matrix<double> m (row,column);
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<m.size1();i++){ 
        int j=0;
        for(j=0;j<m.size2();j++){ 
            m(i,j)=rand();

        }
    }
    v=m;

    return 0;
}

double RenvoiUnCaractere(int row, int column){

    return v(row,column);

}

void Transpose(){

v=trans(v);

}

void MultiplierParUnScalaire(double Scalaire){

v=Scalaire*v;

}

void DestroyMatrice(){

v.clear();

v.resize(1,1);

}
```

When I comment this line of the script :

```
NWMatrix.MatrixCreate(row,column);
```

Node execute all the code and print in the console :

Multiplication Result = 45

The result of the last line of the script.

But when I doesn't comment the line :

```
NWMatrix.MatrixCreate(row,column);
```

Node stop executing the script at the end of the loop.

I think it's a matter of cpp maybe.

I don't destroy properly the object matrix.  I will focus in this point in the next days..

Comment: 'It doesn't work' - can you be more precise?

Comment: Did you succeed to use the dll ? We can do it with ffi, but it is 100 times slower (literally). I failed to initialise functions in a NodeJS addon :/